# How to reference an EntityPlayer method in a class

Tags: java, entity, static-methods, bukkit

I am trying to program a minecraft server, but I need to access the getCurrentActiveItem(or something like that) method from the EntityPlayer class. The reason for needing to do this is to have an item in hand do something like heal the player or something. The problem is, **Nothing is static.** I learned to code from a program called youth Digital, and they don't allow me to edit any code that was not created by me, so I cannot just put static on this method. I did some research and found some pretty specific answers. They were about making a new instance of a class, I guess. Putting it in the code just gives me an error. I have tried stuff like this:

```
EntityPlayer player = new EntityPlayer.class;
public class player = new EntityPlayer.class;
class player = player.instanceOf("EntityPlayer.class");
```

and other similar stuff. All gave me an error that I am not advanced enough to decipher. Here is my code:

```
package myservermod;

import com.youthdigital.servermod.game.*;

public class Player extends PlayerData {

  public Player(EntityPlayer parPlayerObject) {
    super(parPlayerObject);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpdate() {
/*Cheats*/
   //Teleport Cheat
   if(Conditions.cheatEntered("teleport")){
     Actions.teleportPlayers(GameManager.getStringFromCheat(1));
   }
/*Red Team*/
   //Enter the Red Team
   if(Conditions.didRightClickBlock("redTeamEntrance")){
     Actions.teleportPlayers("redTeamBase");
   }
    if(Conditions.didRightClickBlock("dirtBlockBuy")){
      Actions.setBlockWithMetaAtPos("redDirtButton" , Blocks.stone_button, 3);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onJoinedServer(){
    Actions.teleportPlayers("lobby");
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartGame() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onResetGameToLobby() {
    Actions.teleportPlayers("lobby");
  }

  @Override
  public void onRespawned() {

  }

}
```

Comment: So, you're trying to get the active item from a player's hand in Bukkit. Is this it?

Comment: yes. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: This is *not* JavaScript.

Comment: and things like `public class player = new EntityPlayer.class;` could never work because `class` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a type name. Are you trying `Class<EntityPlayer> c = EntityPlayer.class`? Although just like Kerooker said, why would you ever need this? Please learn Java before trying to code Bukkit, it will really help.

Comment: OK, I guess this was a kind of dumb question. I solved it, though.

Comment: @Ptolemy2002 If you found the answer to your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted with a green tick! This helps users with the same problem as you in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you're mentioning what you can't access because it's static.

The thing is, you should not access it in a static way!

`player.getItemInHand()` is a method that must be accessed from an object, so it returns the ItemStack that is in the hand of the `player`, not on a static hand (belongs to no object, therefore nobody!).

What you should do:

1. First, and more important: You should **NEVER** create a new player via new.
   Player is an object created by Bukkit, you shouldn't ever try to create your own new Player.
2. You should get your player by stating who's the player you want to get to bukkit:

To get the ItemStack in a player's hand by the player's name

```
Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer("YourPlayer");    //Notice that the method getPlayer() is static to Bukkit!
ItemStack item = player.getItemInHand();    //Notice that you're accessing your object player, not creating a completely new one, and not accessing it statically!
```

You mostly likely want to detect the Item in Hand from an event, for example to spawn a chicken when you click with a stick:

(Take a look at [the bukkit event handling documentation](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference) for further event-handling knowledge)

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    ItemStack is = player.getItemInHand();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is `getItemInHand` on HumanEntity. [Bukkit JavaDocs](https://jd.bukkit.org/)

Comment: The thing is that I can't reference it because it is not static.

Comment: You wouldn't want to access a static method when you're talking about getting the current item of an entity in game. Static members and variables are for things like class loggers or constants (i.e. Math.PI). You need to have access to the actual instance of a class (the player in game) to access it's public methods like `getItemInHand`.

Comment: Answer should explain how to use the method instead of linking to an external link